# Ring isomorphism for $k(G \oplus \mathbb Z )$ with $G$ torsion-free and abelian

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, abelian-groups, group-rings, ring-isomorphism

Let $k$ be a field and $G$ be a torsion-free abelian group. Then $k[G]$ is an integral domain. If we denote its field of fractions by $F = k(G)$, is it true that $k(G \oplus \mathbb Z )\cong F(X)$?

If not true in general , is it true if $k=\mathbb Q$ ?

Comment: @mathreadler : I have tried finding an isomorphism , but with no progress

Comment: Formally, $k[G\oplus \Bbb{Z}]$ is the ring of functions $G\oplus \Bbb{Z} \to k$ with finite support. But in the category of abelian groups, $G\oplus \Bbb{Z}\simeq G\times \Bbb{Z}$ and so by the canonical isomorphism in set, it is easily seen to be equivalent to a function with finite support $\Bbb{Z}\to (G\to k)$. But the functions $G\to k$ with finite support is $k[G]$, so this is essentially $k[G][\Bbb{Z}] \simeq k[G][X]$

Comment: @Max : I see , thank you ; then $R[\mathbb Z] \cong R[X]$ for any commutative unital ring $R$ , right ?

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in my earlier comment, it's rather $R[\Bbb{N}]\simeq R[X]$. $R[\Bbb{Z}]$ is rather the localisation of $R[X]$ at $X$

Comment: @Max : how do we see that it is the localisation ? Then is my original claim still true ?

Comment: Well in general $R[M]$, where $M$ is a monoid, is essentially a ring with indeterminates $X_m$, for each $m\in M$, that behave like $X_m X_n = X_{mn}$. Having this in mind, with $M=\Bbb{N}$, you see that it's exactly $R[X]$ with the indeterminate $X_n$ being $X$($=X_1$) raised to the power $n$. Now $R[\Bbb{Z}]$ is the same thing except you also have $X_{-1}$, that is, an inverse of $X$. Thus elements of $R[\Bbb{Z}]$ are essentially of the form $X^{-n} P$ where $P\in R[X]$: it is the localization. I do think your claim is true since you consider $k(G\oplus\Bbb{Z})$ and not $k[G\oplus\Bbb{Z}]$

Comment: @Max : but from the comment of Jeremy Rickard here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/258647/is-there-a-field-f-which-is-isomorphic-to-fx-y-but-not-to-fx ; doesn't it seem that my claim is true at least when $k=\mathbb Q$ ?

Comment: Yes, as I said you're considering $k(G\oplus \Bbb{Z})$, and not $k[G\oplus \Bbb{Z}]$. If I'm not wrong in my last comment, $k[G\oplus \Bbb{Z}] \simeq k[G][X]_X$ and so $k(G\oplus \Bbb{Z})$ which is the field of fraction of $k[G\oplus \Bbb{Z}]$ is also the field of fractions of $ k[G][X]_X$, which is $k(G)(X)$ (I think). Try and see if this is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$k(G\oplus\mathbb{Z})$ is always isomorphic to $k(G)(X)$.

I'll write the abelian groups multiplicatively and let $X$ be a generator of $\mathbb{Z}$, so the elements of $G\oplus\mathbb{Z}$ have the form $gX^n$ for $g\in G$ and $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

So $k[G\oplus\mathbb{Z}]$ is isomorphic to $k[G][X,X^{-1}]$.

Finally, for every integral domain $R$ with field of fractions $K$, the field of fractions of $R[X,X^{-1}]$ is isomorphic to $K(X)$, since certainly $R[X,X^{-1}]$ is a subring of $K(X)$, and every element of $K(X)$ is of the form $p(X)/q(X)$ where $p$ and $q$ are polynomials with coefficients in $K$, and multiplying numerator and denominator by a suitable element of $R$ we can assume that $p$ and $q$ have coefficients in $R$, so every element of $K(X)$ is in the field of fractions of $R[X,X^{-1}]$ (or even of $R[X]$).

Comment: then in general , $k[G\oplus \mathbb Z^n] \cong k[G][X_1,...,X_n,X_1^{-1},...,X_n^{-1}]$ for any $n$ ? And do we need $G$ to be torsion free for this to be true ?

Comment: @users Yes, that's right, and it doesn't need $G$ torsion free, except that you don't get an integral domain if it isn't.

Comment: yes okay ; yeah to get the field of fractions only we need the torsion free thing . Thank you

Comment: one more little thing ... so $R[G\oplus \mathbb Z^n] \cong R[G][X_1,...,X_n,X_1^{-1},...,X_n^{-1}]$ for any commutative ring $R$ with unity , right ?

Comment: @users Yes, that's right.

Comment: we can define monoid ring also right (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid_ring) ? Then I guess that $R[M \oplus \mathbb N^k] \cong R[M][X_1,...,X_k]$ for any commutative unital ring $R$ and any abelian monoid $M$ , right ?

Comment: @users Yes, right.