# Fraction field of group ring of field over torsion-free abelian group

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory, abelian-groups, group-rings

> Let $G$ be a torsion-free abelian group. If $k$ is a field, it is known that $k[G]$ is an integral domain. Let $k(G)=\operatorname{Frac} k[G]$. If $G,H$ are torsion-free abelian groups such that $k(G) \cong k(H) $ for every field $k$, then is it true that $G\cong H $ ?

Comment: OK, thanks. In that case I don't know the answer, but there are specific fields for which $k(G)\cong k(H)$ doesn't imply $G\cong H$. For example, $K=\mathbb{Q}(X_1,X_2,\dots)$, the field of rational functions in infinitely many indeterminates, and $G=\mathbb{Z}$ and $H$ the trivial group.

Comment: @JeremyRickard : yeah I can see your example .. because with your $k$ ; $k(\mathbb Z) \cong k(X) \cong k$ [ using https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2336892/ring-isomorphism-for-kg-oplus-mathbb-z-with-g-torsion-free-and-abelian result ] but obviously $\mathbb Z $ is not the trivial group . This is one of the reasons , that I am considering " for every" ...